# First and Last value ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to get this output in Oracle 8i:

```
    column1 |time
    ________|_______
      ABC   | 00:00:01
      END   | 00:00:03
      123   | 00:00:04
      END   | 00:00:07
```

with this output from another query

```
   column1 |time
    ________|_______
      ABC   | 00:00:01
      ABC   | 00:00:02
      ABC   | 00:00:03
      123   | 00:00:04
      123   | 00:00:05
      123   | 00:00:06
      123   | 00:00:07
```

Is there any command for "first" or "last" that I could use here [like in XPath]? Tried to GROUP BY but it doesnt work fine :(

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Oracle 8?  That was out of date more than a decade ago.

Comment: Group on Column1 and Max & Min on time

Comment: @Gordon This Db will not exist anymore after I get this data from it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this in two columns, which would be the more nature approach:

```
select column1, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
from t
group by column1;
```

Do yo really want four rows of output, with `END` on two rows that don't identify what is ending?

EDIT:

To get the output you want:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then column1 else 'END' end) as column1,
       (case when n.n = 1 then firsttime else lasttime end) as "time"
from (select column1, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
      from t
      group by column1
     ) t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n
order by column1, n.n;
```

Note the `order by` clause.  Results are not guaranteed to be in any particular order, and ordering is important for understanding these results.

Comment: Yes, I want to subsitute the value for the string 'END' for the last value for each value. That's weird but that's the requirement I need to integrate this query with another software :)

Comment: I'm trying to bring values from other columns in that are in table t but there's an error. I'll ask another quesiton for it :)

Comment: Important point: The results are ordered. For example, I can have 5 "123"s followed by 3 "ABC"s and then 10 "123"s again. In this case I need start and end for the THREE groups.